# CPU Time of a process in android

Tags: android, shell, process, cpu

I need to get the total cpu time of a process in android. I am trying to use `adb shell` top commands, but it gives only `cpu usage` in terms of percentage.

But I need the total `cpu time` of the process. I can get this info in my `Ubuntu`, but I could not find a way to get the `TIME+` column in android.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would work on a non-rooted device, but:

```
echo $(adb shell ps | grep com.android.phone | awk '{ system("adb shell cat /proc/" $2 "/stat");}' | awk '{print $14+$15;}')
```

This would print the sum of the user mode jiffies and kernel mode jiffies used by the process. Replace com.android.phone with the name of the process you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it on my rooted device and it worked. One more question: How can I get the column names of the table generated by this command: adb shell ps | grep com.xxx.xxx | awk '{ system("adb shell cat /proc/" $2 "/stat");}'

Comment: Run `man proc` and scroll down to the part about `/proc/[pid]/stat`. It lists the names of the fields in order.